# Displaying a UIView in a MobileSubstrate tweak?

Tags: ios, tweak, springboard, theos, cydia-substrate

I am making an iOS MobileSubstrate Tweak and I have hooked Springboard and the launch() method. Now I want to display a view with a button and if it is clicked it would call the %orig (the original code). How can I display a view if I don't have a view controller? I'd appreciate some help. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: See here: http://www.andyibanez.com/2012/07/02/create-a-mobilesubstrate-tweaks/

Comment: This launches a an AlertView, not a view. I need to display a whole view that covers the whole screen and I can add controls to it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you would want to do is to add this
`UIViewController *view = [[UIViewController alloc] init];` 
and then go from there configuring the view how you want.